# can a node be inserted at a non leaf position in a binary search tree?

Tags: data-structures

can a node be inserted in a non leaf position in a binary search tree ?

for eg. if we have the following set of numbers to be arranged as a binary serach tree :-

20.,17,15,19,23,25....

so there is more than 1 way these numbers can be arranged as a bst :-

1. ```
          20
      17      23
   15    19      25
   ```
2. ```
       20
   15      23
     17       25
       19
   ```
3. 25 make it a root and place the other nodes accordingly....

Comment: Technically, a node can be inserted anywhere in the tree. It's just that if it breaks the order or balance, it will have to be restored (BSTs employ the so-called node rotation for that). So, what's the actual question?

Comment: @Alex: A simple BST does not have to be balanced.

Comment: @BjörnPollex: yes, it's just that it will lose all its treeish attractiveness when it degrades into something resembling a linked list.

Comment: @Alex, some types of self-balancing BSTs use rotations, but not all of them. And this question seems to be about plain BSTs, that don't use rotations (or any other way) to balance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A binary search tree is just a tree with certain properties. You can use different algorithms for inserting nodes into such a tree, as long as these algorithms ensure that the properties required for a BST hold. So, yes, you can add nodes in other places than leafes if you want to.

Answer (score 1):

I think you *could* devise some way to do that. But the normal algorithm for inserting into a BST doesn't do it and I don't see any reason why would you want to do that. Also, I don't know about any other publicly known algorithm that does that.